# align a text block to bottom of page

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I am trying to align the version of my windows phone application to bottom center of the page.
It places it to bottom (below) all the components in view. But not to bottom of my page

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Username:" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay}" c4f:TextBinding.UpdateSourceOnChange="True" InputScope="EmailUserName" />
    <TextBlock Text="Password:" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
    <PasswordBox Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" c4f:TextBinding.UpdateSourceOnChange="True" />
    <Button Content="Next" IsEnabled="{Binding CanMoveNext}" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConnectionError}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource TitleSize}"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding VersionNumber}" Height="450" Padding="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

I want it to be at bottom of the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a `Grid` for this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        ...
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding VersionNumber}" Padding="3" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"/>
</Grid>
```

This `Grid` contains two rows. The second row takes as much height as needed by its content, the first row takes the remaining height. A nice article explaining this can be found on visualstudiomagazine.com: [Windows Phone Layout Using Grid](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/05/09/wcmob_layout-using-grid.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `StackPanel` for this, as a `StackPanel` will only use as much space as necessary for its contents (it won't fill the page).

A `Grid` can be a good choice here, as can `DockPanel`, though `DockPanel` isn't available on windows phone. For a `Grid` set up some rows so the bottom element is in the bottom row (where you want it). It could actually be two rows, one for your "main" content and one for the footer.

For the `DockPanel`, set the element that needs to be at the bottom with `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"` and the rest (in order) with `DockPanel.Dock="Top"`. You may need to set the `LastChildFill` property to "False" to get the look you want.

Comment: I don't think the `DockPanel` is available on Windows Phone.

Comment: @venerik I wasn't sure, and the tags were different when I answered :). A grid is likely the way the OP wants to go here.

Comment: Thank you so much Bradley and Venerik. I couldn't add DockPanel. Fixed it with Grid. :)